# I want to change the object to my prev or next object when i click on prev or next button with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

### This my api data

> i fetch my data from my api this is api data in json format

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"heading": "Wellcom to Woodmix",
"disc": "This is our discription and we provide always best and value able product our quality also is better then other",
"img": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/87611/sun-fireball-solar-flare-sunlight-87611.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600"
},
{
"id": "2",
"heading": "Save Nature",
"disc": "stry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a t",
"img": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1420440/pexels-photo-1420440.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=600"
},
{
"id": "3",
"heading": "Pakistan",
"disc": "College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure assage, and going through the cites",
"img": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcReHTRKk6eSVY0cdIDwD_u94q7vzCMqzyxwbA&usqp=CAU"
}
]`
```

### This is my code

> fetch with react **axios** and chang the **reviews state** store the api array in **reviews** using **setReviews**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
const Review = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost/api/read.php').then((res) => {
      setReviews(res.data)
    })
  }, [])
```

### **This is my return**

```
  return (
    <section id='hero'>
      {reviews.map((data) => {
        const { id, heading, disc, img } = data
        return (
          <div
            id='heroCarousel'
            data-bs-interval='5000'
            className='carousel slide carousel-fade'
            data-bs-ride='carousel'
          >
            <ol
              className='carousel-indicators'
              id='hero-carousel-indicators'
            ></ol>
            <div key={id} className='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
              <div className='carousel-item active'>
                <img src={img} alt='' className='w-100 h-100' />
                <div className='carousel-container'>
                  <div className='container'>
                    <h2 className='animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'>
                      {heading}
                    </h2>
                    <p className='animate__animated animate__fadeInUp'>
                      {disc}
                    </p>
                    <a
                      href='#about'
                      className='btn-get-started animate__animated animate__fadeInUp scrollto'
                    >
                      Read More
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <a
              className='carousel-control-prev'
              href='#heroCarousel'
              role='button'
              data-bs-slide='prev'
            >
              <span
                className='carousel-control-prev-icon bi bi-chevron-left'
                aria-hidden='true'
                onClick={prevPerson}
              ></span>
            </a>

            <a
              className='carousel-control-next'
              href='#heroCarousel'
              role='button'
              data-bs-slide='next'
            >
              <span
                className='carousel-control-next-icon bi bi-chevron-right'
                aria-hidden='true'
                // onClick={nextPerson}
              ></span>
            </a>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </section>
  )
}

export default Review
```

**i want to write to function for prevPerson and nextPerson
if any one make this code a carousel then do it please**

Answer (score 0):

### This code working for me

> Blockquote

React

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
const Review = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([]);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .get('http://localhost/api/read.php')
      .then((res) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setReviews(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    let slider = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex((oldIndex) => {
        let index = oldIndex + 1;
        if (index > reviews.length - 1) {
          index = 0;
        }
        return index;
      });
    }, 5000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(slider);
    };
  }, [index]);
  const nextPerson = () => {
    setIndex((oldIndex) => {
      let index = oldIndex + 1;
      if (index > reviews.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
      }
      return index;
    });
  };
  const prevPerson = () => {
    setIndex((oldIndex) => {
      let index = oldIndex - 1;
      if (index < 0) {
        index = reviews.length - 1;
      }
      return index;
    });
  };
  if (loading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }
```

return (

```
    <section id='hero'>
      <div
        key={reviews[index].id}
        id='heroCarousel'
        data-bs-interval='5000'
        className='carousel slide carousel-fade'
        data-bs-ride='carousel'
      >
        <ol className='carousel-indicators' id='hero-carousel-indicators'></ol>
        <div className='carousel-inner' role='listbox'>
          <div className='carousel-item active'>
            <img src={reviews[index].img} alt='' className='w-100 h-100' />
            <div className='carousel-container'>
              <div className='container'>
                <h2 className='animate__animated animate__fadeInDown'>
                  {reviews[index].heading}
                </h2>
                <p className='animate__animated animate__fadeInUp'>
                  {reviews[index].disc}
                </p>
                <a
                  href='#about'
                  className='btn-get-started animate__animated animate__fadeInUp scrollto'
                >
                  Read More
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <a
          className='carousel-control-prev'
          href='#heroCarousel'
          role='button'
          data-bs-slide='prev'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-prev-icon bi bi-chevron-left'
            aria-hidden='true'
            onClick={prevPerson}
          ></span>
        </a>

        <a
          className='carousel-control-next'
          href='#heroCarousel'
          role='button'
          data-bs-slide='next'
        >
          <span
            className='carousel-control-next-icon bi bi-chevron-right'
            aria-hidden='true'
            onClick={nextPerson}
          ></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Review;
```